# how to disappear one page with popup of another page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have one sign in (pop up) page which has register tab in it for sign up, I supposed to make these 2 pages such that when i click on register the sign in page disappear and Registration(sign up) page pops up.But from few days i have been facing some issues as when i click on register the sign up page pops up properly but sign in page does not disappear properly instead it appears in backside of signup page(I have attached a screenshot for this).

Here is my code:

signin.html:

```
{% load static %}

<div class="modal fade" id="signin-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="signin-modalLabel" aria-hidden="true"  data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h2>Sign in</h2>
                        <button class="btn-black-border" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register-modal" id="register">Register</button>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                                     
         
          {# A more "HTML" way of creating the login form#}
    
                        <form method="post" action="{% url 'user_login' %}">
                         {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" required>
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required>

                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="check-data">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="signin" name="signin" value="Sign In">
                                    <label for="signin" class="checkbox-label">Stay signed in</label>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#" title="Forgot your password?" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forgot-modal" id="forgot-psw">Forgot your password?</a>
                            </div>
                            

                            <button type="submit" class="btn-red" value="Login">Sign in</button>
                            <p title="Trouble signing in?" class="trouble text-center">Trouble signing in?</p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn-border google"><i><img src="{% static 'images/google.svg' %}" alt="google"></i><a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}"><em>Continue with Google</em></a></button>
                        <button class="btn-border facebook"><i><img src="{% static 'images/facebook.svg' %}" alt="facebook"></i><a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}"><em>Continue with Facebook</em></a></button>
                        <button class="btn-border apple"><i><img src="{% static 'images/apple.svg' %}" alt="apple"></i><a><em>Continue with Apple</em></a></button>
            

    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Sign up page html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="register-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="forgot-modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h2>Register</h2>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                          <form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
                          {% comment %} {% if messages %}
                            {% for message in messages %}
                            <p {% if message.tags %} class="alert alert-{{message.tags}} mb-5" {% endif %}>{{message}}}</p>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %} {% endcomment %}
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="first_name">First Name <span style="color: #FA4A0C;">&#42;</span></label>
                                <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="first name" class="form-control" required>
                                
                            </div>
                               <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="last_name">Last Name <span style="color: #FA4A0C;">&#42;</span></label>
                                <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="last name" class="form-control" required>
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username">Email <span style="color: #FA4A0C;">&#42;</span></label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" class="form-control" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" required>
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Password <span style="color: #FA4A0C;">&#42;</span></label>
                                <input type="password" id="psw"  name="password" placeholder="Password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" class="form-control" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required>

                                
                            </div>
                            <div id="message">
                            <h3>Password must contain the following:</h3>
                            <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
                            <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
                            <p id="number" class="invalid">A <b>number</b></p>
                            <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 characters</b></p>
                            </div>
                         <!--   <div class="check-data">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="signin" name="signin" value="Sign In">
                                    <label for="signin" class="checkbox-label">Stay signed in</label>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#" title="Forgot your password?" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forgot-modal" id="forgot-psw">Forgot your password?</a>
                            </div> !-->
                            

                            <button type="submit" class="btn-red" value="Login">Sign up</button>
                            {% comment %} {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                            <p class="alert alert-danger my-3">{{error}}</p>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}  {% endcomment %}
                            
                        </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <em>Already Have an Account?</em> <a href="#" title="Sign In" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signin-modal" id="sign-in"> Sign In</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Any idea for css or js or html would be appreciated as it is very important.[image]

Comment: You've not given any code examples or any indication of what (if any) frameworks you're using. That's the bare minimum anyone would need to answer your question.

Comment: Can you provide the source code and describe the errors you are facing?

Comment: i was expecting the answer with some javascript directly without any code given. but this aint possible. so provided a code please check.

Comment: What is `{% load static %}`? It's non of the tagged languages.

Comment: sorry its my mistake as a beginner..i just tag the language its django(python) based web app

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a minor mistake that occurred because I added the same JavaScript file link 2 times in my HTML file, so one link is supposed to open one popup and other link is opening another popup without closing the first one.